# Align text to center of object in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph-styles

I want to make this text centered within the white rectangle.

[image]

I have tried using the Text Frame Options and setting vertical justification to "center', but it's still not quite aligned-- there's too much space at the top.

[image]

I thought maybe I could add space above or below the text instead. But when I look at the Paragraph window, I don't have an option to add space above or below the paragraph. clicking on the circled tool makes space between the lines, not before the paragraph.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is related to the *First Baseline Offset* setting of the text frame.

You can access the *Text Frame Options* of a text frame by by selecting it and either right-clicking it and choosing *Text Frame Options* or pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on PC.

Under the *Baseline Options* tab you'll find the *First Baseline > Offset* which specifies the vertical position of the first baseline of the text frame.

[image]

The default setting is *Ascent*, but as you see there are five different options.

Assuming you have set the *Vertical Justification > Align* to *Center* they will give you these different results:

[image]

*Ascent*, *Cap Height* and *x Height* uses info found in the font file. *Leading* uses the leading of the text. *Fixed* allows for any custom position on or below the top edge of the frame.

You should probably use *Cap Height* (if you want to center the text according to the uppercase letters) or *x Height* (if you want to center the text according to the lowercase letters).

Comment: @ale19, thanks for accepting. I've just updated the answer - there was an error in the second image.

Comment: gotcha, thanks! Do you know why I don't have an option to add space before/after a paragraph in the Paragraph menu? (Should this be a separate question?)

Comment: @ale19, it *should* be a separate question, but I'll still tell you. Space before/after only works *between* paragraphs (which is good - would be very annoying for longer texts to constantly change style according to the paragraph's position in the text frame). If you want to raise or lower text either use the "fixed" *First Baseline Offset* or use *Baseline Shift*.

Comment: ... or use the text frame's "Inset Spacing" to control text position. Many options. See it like a kind of programming with a lot of tools at your disposal.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

First, make the frame fit the text dimensions with button 1
Second, align both with vertical middle with button 2

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE. Sorry, but I have to downvote your answer since it give the same result as the OP already had only with two frames instead of one.